# Add "Notify" option

Tags: feature-request, notifications

At mathoverflow.net there is an "Notify" box where you can choose to get emails about any updates on questions you choose. It would be great to have the same thing at MSE.

Comment: It *would* be nice if Starred questions would add to your notifications, rather than just a red flag when you actually look at your user profile.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/mark-problems-as-notify-me-if-answer-is-posted)

Comment: @MartinSleziak This seems to be requesting notifications for more than just new answers. Personally I'd be more interested in new comments than new answers, especially for starred questions like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/221152/12952) which aren't likely to get a real answer any time soon.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber The [other one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/) includes the possibility: *get all notifications that you would get if you were the original poster*; which means comments on the question and answers (but not comments on answers). Of course, for favorite questions you get [much more notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work), but they do not appear in you inbox.